# jQuery Mouseout Issue with remove() method

Tags: jquery

I am having some difficulty here understand a concept. I am trying to create a jQuery script where on mouseenter over a div element there would be a button that shows up on top of the div element.  This part is working just fine.  However, when I mouseout I am not sure how to tell jQuery to remove whatever button was created.  I tried to use remove() method however with that, on mouseenter again the button was not showing up.  Please assist.

HTML:
    
        
        
        
        
        Hello</button> -->

```
    <!-- Include JS Files -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/tag_custom.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.divbutton {
    height: 100px;
    background: #0000ff;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).on('mouseenter', 'div', function () {
        // check if there's already an added data, if not set status to false
        var status = $(this).data('added') || false;
        // if status is false then create a new element
        if (!status) {
            var tag = $('<button>', {
                text: 'Tagit',
                'class': 'tagit_click',
                click: function(){
                    // TODO: fetch and save data to JSON from here
                    console.log(this);
                }
            })
            // append the element and set the added to true so we don't do that stuff next time
            $(this).append(tag).data('added', true);
        }

    }).mouseout(function(){
        // hide or remove the tagit button on mouseout
    })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FWG8R/277/

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing `.has()` , `.is()` to check if `div` contains `.tagit_click` element.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(this).on("mouseenter", "div", function () {
        // does `div` contain `tagit_click` element ?
        // if not, create `button` element ,
        // append `button` to `div`
        if (!$(this).has(".tagit_click").is("*")) {
            var tag = $("<button>", {
                "text": "Tagit",
                "class": "tagit_click",
                "click": function () {
                    // TODO: fetch and save data to JSON from here
                    console.log(this);
                }
            })
            $(this).append(tag);
        }

    }).on("mouseout", function () {
        // hide or remove `button` on `mouseout`
        $(".tagit_click").detach()            
    })
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FWG8R/280/